# Deleting Rows in Excel using Date Criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of rows with a header row at the top.
I need to delete any row that has the following criteria

1. Starting in row 2, if the value in Column E is "001535" and the Date in Column O is Less than 7/1/2002.

This is the code I have tried

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = [a1].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 5).Value = "001535" And CDate(Cells(x, 15)) < CDate("02/01/2003") Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next x
    End Sub
```

I believe the `For x = [a1].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1` designates the Header Row as a special row to not include in the criteria

The problem is that I get a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Comment: You'd avoid row 1 by using `To 2`, not `To 1`, but the type mismatch is likely bc you have error values, or non-datelike values.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at data, it can be concluded where exactly the issue is. However, it can be inferred that your column 'O', which should be date may have at least one value (row) that is other than date, hence causing type mismatch error.

The solution can be either you have to clean the data (making entire column date) or make adjustments in your code by introducing Error Handling aspect (On Error GoTo).

One more thing can be, if you have cleaned data already, try to exclude headers by amending one line of code to:

For x = [a1].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 2 Step -1

Comment: Thank You folks. I had 2 things going on.